# UITableView with 3x3 grid button subviews

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Im really struggling to get this to work efficiently. Basically I need a 3x3 scrolling grid of buttons. I need to know which of these buttons is pressed and so I do the following when I create a new cell

```
    button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80);
    button1.opaque = NO;
    button1.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button1.tag = 0;
    [foodCell.contentView addSubview:button1];


    button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(120, 20, 80, 80);
    button2.opaque = NO;
    button2.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    button2.tag = 1;
    [foodCell.contentView addSubview:button2];


    button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button3.frame = CGRectMake(220, 20, 80, 80);
    button3.opaque = NO;
    button3.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    button3.tag = 2;
    [foodCell.contentView addSubview:button3];`
```

Now when a button is pressed I get the cell using superviews and then do a bit of math using the tags to figure out which index in my array I need to look at. This seems to work but I also need to display a checkmark over buttons which have been pressed, kind of like a shopping list where once an item is pressed it would be ticked off and could also be un-ticked. I am struggling to find an efficient way of acheiving all of this.... Does anyone have any thoughts, I would really appreciate anything as Ive been stuck for a while now.

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get the instance of the clicked button from the `sender` of your action `buttonClick:` and then add a view resembling your check-mark over that button?

Comment: Ok I tried that but for some reason when I add the checkmark to the sender it adds a checkmark to several buttons..... I think its to do with the way I have added the buttons to the tableView above? Any ideas?

Comment: Does it add it to every button in the cell? Or does it add it to every first/second/third button of each cell? It may depend on the fact that you use the same pointer to refer to button1/2/3 for each cell

Comment: If I add it to the 1st button in a cell then every 5th cell in the table, the 1st button will have the checkmark? Perhaps how Im adding the buttons in deque? Im a little lost I must admit... Many thanks again

Comment: Why don't you try to define the UIButtons pointers and init them in the same method?

Comment: I am actually doing that CustomButton *button1 = nil;
                  CustomButton *button2 = nil;
                  CustomButton *button3 = nil; but this doesnt have any affect. This is driving me crazy, surely its something stupid Im missing??

Comment: where are you doing that? inside the same method?

Comment: I do this all in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath, under the condition that a new cell needs to be created...

Comment: Thats probably a good idea... .but without sounding like too much of an idiot how and what is a pastebin?? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It's a site where you can paste your code and share the link http://pastebin.com/